# renaming app.config or referring it from subfolder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, configuration-files

We have decided to upgrade our project from .NET 4.0 to 4.5.2 but want to keep support of .Net 4.0 as it is.

So we have created copy of each CSPROJ file in the same directory one for 4.0 and and other for 4.5.2, but they are referring to same app.config file.

How can I have 2 app.config files for each project?

Comment: Why not require every user to upgrade to 4.5.2?  I think this doesn't sound like a good idea, it sounds like it will cause more trouble targeting two frameworks than it will be worth.

Comment: We need to continue support of product on windows XP and 4.5.2 is supported on XP. Hence we need to continue support of 4.0

Comment: If you use a source control system you could create a branch that will contain the .net 4.0 version and make the 4.5.2 version the "main" branch.
Then you can periodically merge back your changes from the main 4.5.2 branch into the 4.0 branch. To me this would be a more clean cut way. When you merge from the "new" branch you will actively decide what you put in the "old" branch and do any necessary workarounds to keep the old branch alive.